# How to use npm-installed cesium for browser

Tags: javascript, npm, cesiumjs

Cesium is now on npm. After `npm install cesium`-ing into my project, all codes go into `node_modules`.

In the cesium [hello world](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/1.18/Apps/HelloWorld.html), it includes `cesium` by something like `<script src="your/path/to/Cesium.js"></script>`

My question is, what additional steps I need to do in order to use cesium from html?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways.  If the `node_modules` folder itself is being served, you can just pull Cesium from there.  During debugging, use the un-minified version:

```
<script src="node_modules/cesium/Build/CesiumUnminified/Cesium.js"></script>
<style>
    @import url(node_modules/cesium/Build/CesiumUnminified/Widgets/widgets.css);
</style>
```

But for production, use the minified version:

```
<script src="node_modules/cesium/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
<style>
    @import url(node_modules/cesium/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css);
</style>
```

There's another option as well.  You can use `npm` to pull down a copy of `require.js`, and then require in only the specific modules of Cesium you need, from the Cesium source tree in `node_modules\cesium\Source`.  This results in your project including less JavaScript than pulling in the whole combined file, and allows easier debugging, because of the separate files.  But it results in more network requests, so you wouldn't want this directly in a production environment without some kind of build system to combine and minify the files you use.

There's some additional detail on the [blog post introducing npm cesium](http://cesiumjs.org/2015/12/14/Cesium-npm/). (written by Matt Amato, who also provided some comments below)

Comment: For AMD modules, you should not use `node_modules/cesium/node_modules/requirejs/require.js` and instead depend on requirejs in your package.json directly.

Comment: Also, if AMD/requireJS isn't you thing, you can use Webpack, which is becoming one of the most popular bundlers.  We recently had a blog post about it: http://cesiumjs.org/2016/01/26/Cesium-and-Webpack/

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I edited the answer to direct people to use the separate require.js.  Let me know if further edits are needed.

Comment: @emackey Thank you for your answer! Indeed my question was inspired after read Mattew's article http://cesiumjs.org/2015/12/14/Cesium-npm/. I do want to include cesium as AMD modules. Would love to have a more detailed procedures on using requirejs as I'm less experienced on front-end development

Comment: My recommendation (and I'm not sure if Matt would agree) is that less-experienced developers start with the combined version, as shown at the top of my answer.  There's a lot less that can go wrong, and it's easy to switch to un-minified for debugging and minified for production.

Comment: It would be better to restrict the static serve to the cesium Build directory only: e.g. `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/cesium/Build/')));`

Comment: @wulfgarpro For using the combined or minified Cesium, yes, you can restrict to the Build folder, or even to the `Cesium` or `CesiumUnminified` subfolder inside of Build.  But to follow Matt's advice and use requirejs, you will need access to the `Source` folder, above Build.  Good point about not serving the rest of node_modules though, thanks!